# Login Page Looping

Tags: php, forms

I'm pretty new to PHP, but I decided to try and make a simple login page on my test website, just to see how things work. I know it's not very secure, but I'm not worrying too much about that yet. The problem I am having is when I try to login, be the username correct or not, I am redirected to the login page instantly. I don't think it is even going to the PHP script that checks the username and password or anything, since I get the same results when I use an incorrect username or password. I'm not entirely sure if this is a PHP problem or not, since the form is in HTML, so sorry if it's not.

Login Page:

```
<?
include"includes/head.inc";
?>

    <div class="login" align="center";>

    <h1>Log In</h1>

    <form action="/cp/login.php" method="post">

        <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="username">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Password
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit">

    </form>

    </div>

    <?
    include"includes/footer.inc";
    ?>
```

Login.php:

```
<?
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

session_start();
include"../includes/connect.inc";

$q = "SELECT * from users where email='$username' and password='MD5($password)'";
$result = mysql_query($q, $connection) or die
("Could not execute query : $q." . mysql_error());

if (!$result) {

    echo "<h1>Incorrect username or password.</h1>";

}
else {
    $r              = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $login_username = $r["email"];
    session_register("login_username");
    Header("Location: protected.php");
}

?>
```

Protected.php:

```
<?
session_start();
if ($login_username == "") {
    Header("Location: ../login.php");
}
else {
    include"../includes/head.inc";
    include"../cp.inc";
    include"../includes/footer.inc";
}
?>
```

I included all the files just in case they are needed, but it seems to just be looping the login page, not cycling through the others. The username and password I am entering are correct, and worked in my previous login system before I rewrote it to make it work better. I hope I'm not missing anything silly or obvious. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: ...also, using prepared statements will remedy the woeful SQL injection vulnerability of your login system.

Comment: Don't use MD5 (it isn't secure) and don't use unsalted passwords. See the section on [passwords in the PHP FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that might cause this:

```
session_start();
if($login_username=="") {
```

You're referring to something inside the session; this is how you should do that:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login_username']) || $_SESSION['login_username']=="") {
```

---

Another small issue:

```
<?
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

session_start();
```

You should test the `$_POST` keys first before attempting to access them.

```
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
    die("Invalid page request");
}
session_start();
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
```

---

Last but not least, learn PDO; see also the page here that warns about continued use of `mysql_` functions: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: I added those changes and everything is working, thank you very much! I'm off to read more about this PDO.

Comment: @Mittens great, if this helped you consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer :)

Comment: Well, this is odd.. I have made no changes to anything on the site, server, or script since I last tested it, but now it's not working again, doing the same thing as before.. I wondered if it was just my database being shitty, but it's not even coming up with an error or anything, just reloads the login page. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It's probably looping because you forgot to check for mysql_num_rows() inside login.php. Instead you check if mysql_query() returned false, but because you added 'or die()' it will be truthy at that point.

Comment: @mittens did you get my earlier comment?

Comment: Yes, and I clicked on the check mark. Is there something else I am missing? I'm new to the layout of stackoverflow.com